# PHP base_convert?

Tags: php, unique

Will the output prododuced by the following function always be unique?

```
base_convert(uniqid(), 10, 36);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqid is not guaranteeed to be unique. If you are running your script on multiple servers they may run the call at the exact same microsecond and give the same result. This is very unlikely however.

Moreover, uniqid does not return a base-10 number so your code will definitely NOT give a unique result.

Comment: okay, as u said it doesnt return base 10, how should i convert the uniqid base? thanks.

Comment: @sunjie: Why would you want to convert the `uniqid()` result? Into what?

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig, ok, i would want to generate random names for the files, but would like to keep them unique so that they dont conflict, thats why using uniqid. ALSO i would like to keep the names short, so thought this could work, no?

Comment: It's base-16 so just change the second parameter.

Comment: @Emil Vikström, Did you mean `base_convert(uniqid(), 16, 36); `

Answer (score 0):

not as random as you want to. if you are on linux, better read from `/dev/random`

Comment: Still not guaranteed to be unique though for a single instance.